# Implement the facebook connect on uiwebview using HTML5/JavaSCript for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiwebview

I need to implement the facebook connent on UIWebview using HTML5/ Javascript. Presently what I implemented is working fine on iphone safari but not in native application. Please Suggest. Thanks

Comment: Post your code, without it we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

when the app loads up have it open a web view that point to a website that does what you want it to. see facebooks graph api documentation for web apps/websites

Comment: I need Facebook API to be work on my native application's webview. As I am using UIwebview than I am unable to implement iphone Graph API and I am working on native application, the website facebook connect not fuctioning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this kind of app also. I haven't finished it yet but after googling I found just this link that seems to work with UIWebView

http://suhinini.me/2011/05/24/embedding-facebook-social-comments-plugin-to-an-ios-application/

I've tried the HTML5 code on the comment plugin page but it doesn't work. The UIWebView just shows nothing.
I'm still looking for the best solution.

edited

Ok now I got my app working. What I did was creating a HTML file, containing the code from facebook comment plugin page, and put it in my project (I think this should work fine with file on server also). I use this

```
[UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL:]
```

since my HTML file is local.

This is the facebook comment plugin page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/